# Why calling executeBatch() from PreparedStatement is very slow?

Tags: java, oracle, apache-spark

I'm using Spark to insert records into Oracle DB.

The job will call `executeBatch()` when the batch size reaches 100K. However, this call is taking far too long. I've attached the thread dump, please explain to me what could be the possible issue here? is there something that need to be configured at Oracle side?

```
    Thread 66: Executor task launch worker-4 (RUNNABLE)
    java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite0(Native Method)
    java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite(SocketOutputStream.java:113)
    java.net.SocketOutputStream.write(SocketOutputStream.java:159)
    oracle.net.ns.DataPacket.send(DataPacket.java:150)
    oracle.net.ns.NetOutputStream.write(NetOutputStream.java:145)
    oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CMAREngine.marshalCLR(T4CMAREngine.java:659)
    oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CMAREngine.marshalCLR(T4CMAREngine.java:634)
    oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIrxd.marshal(T4CTTIrxd.java:619)
    oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.marshalBinds(T4C8Oall.java:1794)
    oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.marshalAll(T4C8Oall.java:1251)
    oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.marshal(T4C8Oall.java:542)
    oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.doOall8(T4CPreparedStatement.java:180)
    oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.executeForRows(T4CPreparedStatement.java:953)
    oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeForRowsWithTimeout(OraclePreparedStatement.java:9215)
    oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeBatch(OraclePreparedStatement.java:9315)
    oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatementWrapper.executeBatch(OracleStatementWrapper.java:211)
    com.data.pro.DBStore$InsertFunction.call(DBStore.java:250)
    com.data.pro.DBStore$InsertFunction.call(DBStore.java:148)
    org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaRDDLike$$anonfun$foreachPartition$1.apply(JavaRDDLike.scala:195)
    org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaRDDLike$$anonfun$foreachPartition$1.apply(JavaRDDLike.scala:195)
    org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$foreachPartition$1.apply(RDD.scala:773)
    org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$foreachPartition$1.apply(RDD.scala:773)
    org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$runJob$4.apply(SparkContext.scala:1319)
    org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$runJob$4.apply(SparkContext.scala:1319)
    org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:61)
    org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:56)
    org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:196)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

```
public class DBStore {
    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(DBStore.class);

    public static class InsertFunction implements
            VoidFunction<Iterator<Tuple2<String, String>>> {

        private static final long serialVersionUID = 999955766876878L;
        private String dbuser = "";
        private String dbpass = "";
        private int batchsize;

        public InsertFunction(String dbuser, String dbpass, int batchsize) {
            super();
            this.dbuser = dbuser;
            this.dbuser = dbuser;
            this.batchsize = batchsize;
        }

        @Override
        public void call(Iterator<Tuple2<String, String>> results) {
            Connection connect = null;
            PreparedStatement pstmt = null;
            try {
                connect = getDBConnection(dbuser, dbpass);

                int count = 0;

                if (batchsize <= 0) {
                    batchsize = 10000;
                }

                pstmt = connect
                        .prepareStatement("MERGE INTO server_det a USING ("
                                + "Select ? Domain_Name, ? site_type, ? data_transfered FROM dual) B On (A.Domain_Name = B.Domain_Name and A.site_type = B.site_type) "
                                + "When Matched Then "
                                + "Update Set A.data_transfered = B.data_transfered "
                                + "When Not Matched Then "
                                + "Insert ( A.Domain_Name, A.data_transfered, A.site_type ) "
                                + "Values ( B.Domain_Name, B.data_transfered, B.site_type )");

                while (results.hasNext()) {

                    Tuple2<String, String> kv = results.next();

                    String[] data = kv._1.concat("," + kv._2).split(",");

                    pstmt.setString(1, data[0].toString());
                    pstmt.setDouble(2, Double.parseDouble(data[1].toString()));
                    pstmt.setString(3, data[2].toString());

                    pstmt.addBatch();

                    count++;

                    if (count == batchsize) {
                        pstmt.executeBatch();
                        count = 0;
                    }

                }

                pstmt.executeBatch();
                connect.commit();

            } catch (Exception e) {
                logger.error("InsertFunction error: " + e.getMessage());
            } finally {

                try {

                    if (pstmt != null) {
                        pstmt.close();
                    }
                    connect.close();
                } catch (SQLException e) {
                    logger.error("InsertFunction Connection Close error: "
                            + e.getMessage());
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, do you mean you call `addBatch` 100k times before calling `executeBatch`? Have you tried reducing the batch size to, say, 1k or 10k and seeing if that had an affect?

Comment: @SeanBright - Sorry if I was not clear in my post. I will call addBatch 100K times as part of preparestatement but will only call executeBatch when the batch size reached to 100K. So if I have 1M records then it will call executeBatch 10 times only. I've tried reducing the batch size but no joy.  in above snippet "com.data.pro.DBStore$InsertFunction.call(DBStore.java:250)" it's calling executeBatch method.

Comment: When you say _"far too long"_ - how long is that?

Comment: A batch doesn't reduce the number of SQL statements getting executed on the database, so when you execute a batch, you are executing 100k statements, which is likely to take a long time.

Comment: @SeanBright and GriffeyGog1, just to give you an idea I have 4 parallel tasks that insert about 5million of records, which takes around ~1 hour. Is this expected?

Comment: It would really help if we saw some code.  Otherwise, this is a lot of speculation.

Comment: [Oracle Update Batching](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/JJDBC/oraperf.htm#i1058859): `Batch values between 5 and 30 tend to be the most effective. Setting a very high value might even have a negative effect.`

Comment: Is insert is plain `insert` call into database? or its via procedure? Also, did you tried adding `/*+APPEND*/`  hint into insert?

Comment: @sstan, I'm having problem sharing the code here (complaining about format). I've shared the code on pastie:
http://pastie.org/10308108

Comment: Code is added to the post. thanks

Comment: Well, this is not just pure inserting.  This is a merge statement. So Oracle has extra work to do.  Maybe the times you are getting are not entirely unreasonable, especially if the table you are inserting into is very large to begin with.  You do have proper indexes on your `Domain_Name` and `site_type` columns, right?

Comment: @sstan, We created a new db and table for this job. But this jobs does insert/merge about ~5million of records but didn't expect to take this long.

Comment: How big is your table before you start the merging of the 5 million records?  And do you really need to do a merge?  Are there really records that need to be updated rather than inserted?

Comment: @sstan, the table was empty when we first executed the job. So the first job inserted 5Million of records, which took an hour. Then the later jobs were inserting/merging around the same/more data. But I must say that later jobs were a little bit  better as they wereprocessing in ~55 minutes. Not a massive improvement.

Comment: One thing I would do is attempting a pure insert (no merge) of 5million records in an empty table, just to see if there is a significant performance improvement.  This would help isolate whether the problem is merge-specific or something else. And you may not have seen my other question, but do you really need to account for updates between job runs?  Do you try to reinsert the same records again, and that's why you need the merge?

Comment: @sstan, thanks for your suggestion. I'll try the pure insert and see if that make any difference. I'll update you once I've completed that task. Yes, you are correct that recompute process will reinsert some of the records so it requires to merge/update them instead of reinserting.